# How to allow a certain group to only run a specific on a server using salt-ssh (puppet config)?

Tags: ssh, puppet, salt-stack

As a disclaimer I'm a volunteer at a understaffed non profit and don't have too much knowledge but am trying to help out with something a bit above my paygrade.

Basically, we have a salt module in our puppet configuration which allows users with root access on our main puppet server to run commands on all other servers from there using "salt-ssh -E '.*' cmd.run '[insert comand here]'

What I would want to know how to do is how to configure it so that users in specific group (not root users) can only use salt-ssh in order to run one specific command on one specific server from the main puppet server. This would have to be configured in Puppet.

Comment: To start, figure out *which* salt module you are using.  You can find this in the module's `metadata.json` file, but if you have root access to the Puppet server then the easiest way to get the full module name (and version) would probably be to open a root shell and in it run `puppet module list`.

Comment: You'll very likely also need a lot more familiarity with Salt than I have.  Asking here may get you some useful information, but more than likely, you're going to want to read [the Salt documentation](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/contents.html), or at least some of it.  And unless it happens to be the case that the Puppet module you're using has a straightforward way to accomplish your goal, your question is probably too broad for SO in its current form.

Comment: Salt has https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/eauth/ but I don't know whether it works with Salt-SSH.